# Pink LED on case with high processing C++ program

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, case, led

I have written a very intensive program in C++ that should loop on some code for a quite long time.

I can't explain why, after few minutes, the program stops working (I don't see any output) and a pink LED on my case appears. When I kill the program the LED simply vanishes.

I have Ubuntu 14.04 with i7 core. Could be an i7 kind of prevention for high temperature?

Comment: Is it the HDD LED? Maybe it's eating all your RAM and OS starts paging to hard disk.

Comment: @gronostaj right, memory is full! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it the HDD LED?

Maybe the program is eating all your RAM and OS starts paging to hard disk.

<sub>*(I have originally posted this suggestion as a comment and OP confirmed that it's correct)*</sub>